# Can't mount routes, even though registerRoute function is called

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to write a simple Ktor app. I've got a file called `ImageRoutes.kt`:

```
package my.keddad.routes

// some imports here

fun Route.imageRouting() {
    route("/image") {
        post {
            // some logic here
        }
    }
}

fun Application.registerImageRoutes() {
    routing {
        imageRouting()
    }
}
```

I want to mount those routes. To do so, I add my `registerImageRoutes()` function to `embeddedServer` configuration. My `Application.kt`:

```
package my.keddad

import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import my.keddad.plugins.*
import my.keddad.routes.registerImageRoutes

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        configureRouting()
        configureHTTP()
        configureMonitoring()
        configureSerialization()
        registerImageRoutes()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

When I start my code, `registerImageRoutes` function is called, but, apperently, no routes are added - I get 404 errors when trying to use them:

```
2021-12-01 00:45:37.015 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
2021-12-01 00:45:37.083 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
2021-12-01 00:45:37.083 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Application started in 0.079 seconds.
2021-12-01 00:45:37.084 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Application started: io.ktor.application.Application@1a677343
2021-12-01 00:45:39.699 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] INFO  ktor.application - 404 Not Found: post - /image
```

Documentation also suggests adding my route registration function to `Application.module`, however, that also doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how my trace looks like:

```
2021-12-01 10:02:54.375 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE ktor.application - Trace for [image]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /image, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /image
    /image/(method:POST), segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /image/(method:POST)
Matched routes:
  No results
Route resolve result:
  FAILURE "No matched subtrees found" @ /
```

I'm not sure what that means. It does know that there is a `/image` route registered, but it can't find the handler for POST to that URI?

Actually, it looks like it has something to do with request type. When running tests, like this:

```
 withTestApplication({ configureRouting() }) {
            with(handleRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/image"){
...

            }
```

I get 404. When using curl like this:

```
curl -v -X post http://localhost:8080/image
```

I also get 404. However, when using curl with "post" in capital letters, it does work as expected:

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8080/image
```

I'm also confused by the trace, which looks just like the trace for failed requests (with the exception of it actually finding the route):

```
2021-12-01 11:21:33.369 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE ktor.application - Trace for [image]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /image, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /image
    /image/(method:POST), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /image/(method:POST)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "image" -> "(method:POST)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /image/(method:POST)
```

Comment: It could return the 404 status if the `post {}` route doesn't contain code for the actual responding, e.g. `call.respondText`. To troubleshoot it you can trace your routes https://ktor.io/docs/tracing-routes.html.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman not really the case here. I added the trace, and it looks like my route isn't even called

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the routes were actually mounted just fine. The problem was with how I tested my code - I didn't add registration functions to `withTestApplication`, and that caused the tests to fail.